# DotNetNuke replacement for PortalModuleBase

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke

I'm creating a new DotNetNuke module and in the past I inherited from PortalModuleBase. I'm aware that there's a replacement for this now. Can someone please tell me what it is? I've had a brief search for it but I haven't found what it is.

Comment: Are you thinking about the WebForms MVP model of development?  That's more than just a change of base class, and involves a whole new paradigm of development.  You can take a look at the Messaging and Taxonomy modules in the DotNetNuke source package to see how they're structured and what the various parts inherit from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there's a replacement for `PortalModuleBase` yet? At least not that I'm teaching in any of my DotNetNuke classes :D

Are you perhaps thinking of a replacement for `IHydratable` on your object class with `ContentItem`?

**EDIT**: There are some other base classes available now though after doing some digging. Such as `UserUserControlBase`, `ProfileUserControlBase`, `UserModuleBase`, and others. Look at the `DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules` namespace for a full listing.

Comment: For most module development, `PortalModuleBase` is going to be all that you need.  If you're integrating with some particular part of DNN (user profile, authentication) then one of these other `ModuleBase` classes may help or be necessary.